# eloquent query doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

i'm trying to query my mysql database with eloquent laravel but it doesn't work.

```
User::where('id', 1)->first()
```

however when i try with sql query it works.

```
DB::table('users')->first()
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can You please attach error? If first line just returns null, please attach `User.php`.

Comment: check on your User model whether there is any table mapping or not, for example check "protected $table = 'user_table_name' " this in your model class.................or simply post your error message make sure that you have set your error reporting on.

Answer (score 1):

May be you didn't use your User namespace. If not, use your User model namespace in controller.

Comment: i'm using User Model namespace. I have an another database that is identical to this , so for that one it works. this problem is really gets on my nerves.